# tkinter themes causing program to lag

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, pycharm, themes

able frame in tkinter, the frame consist of multiple mini long canvases(which contain some text and a button)which can be scrolled up and down with a scrollbar. I also used tkinter themes to make my gui look nice. But for some reason as soon as i added in the gui, the frame would lag abit when scrolled up and down, like the canvases are crashing into eachother, is their away to fix this?

Here is how it looks without scrolling
[image]

Here's how it looks sometimes, when its scrolled 
[image]

Here's the code

```
from tkinter import *
from ttkthemes.themed_tk import ThemedTk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
class tkinterprogram(ThemedTk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ThemedTk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage,Task):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry("1024x720")

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        l = Canvas(self, bg='#4A4949')
        l.pack(fill='both', expand='True')
        global canvascon
        canvascon = Canvas(l, height=400,width=1500,bg='#4A4949',highlightthickness=0)
        global frame2
        frame2 = Frame(canvascon)
        global myscrollbar
        myscrollbar = Scrollbar(l, orient="vertical",command=canvascon.yview) 
        canvascon.create_window((0, 0), window=frame2,width=15000,anchor='nw')
        canvascon.place(x=25,y=150,relheight=0.558,relwidth=0.87)
        myscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y,pady=25)
        Button(l,text='go',command=lambda: meth()).pack()

def meth():
    for count in range(25):
        c = Canvas(frame2, height=50, bg="#1E2133",highlightthickness=5,highlightbackground='#4A4949')
        lab = tk.Label(frame2, text='running',bg='#1E2133',fg='#EFEFEF')
        lab_window = c.create_window(10,15, window=lab,anchor=tk.NW)
        stop = tk.Button(frame2, text='STOP')
        stop_window = c.create_window(200, 15, window=stop, anchor=tk.NW)
        c.pack(fill=X,expand=True)
        frame2.update()  # update frame2 height so it's no longer 0 ( height is 0 when it has just been created )
        canvascon.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set, scrollregion="0 0 0 %s" % frame2.winfo_height())

class Task(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)



app = tkinterprogram()
app.get_themes()
app.set_theme('scidgrey')
app.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help in advance.